# What is the latest updated Tutorial I can find regarding developing dApps?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, blockchain, private-blockchain

I am new to Blockchain technology and Ethereum. Most of the tutorials I referred aren't applicable and I always hit bottlenecks. I need to set up a very simple application to demo a blockchains use in the supply chain using Ethereum. Can someone recommend me a good reference to refer to inorder to set up an application?

Comment: There is a 10 Steps Tutorial for developing DApps with Parity available at https://github.com/ethcore/parity/wiki/Tutorial-Part-I

Answer (score 1):

First of all you can start by reading the Ethereum [whitepaper](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/White-Paper). It is a very good introduction to blockchain and ethereum.

Then, if you want to get deeper understanding of programming on ethereum you can check Solidity's [documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/).

> Solidity is a contract-oriented, high-level language whose syntax is similar to that of JavaScript and it is designed to target the Ethereum Virtual Machine.

I myself am a complete beginner in this fields and found these resources quite enlightening.

You could also watch the Devcon videos on the Ethereum youtube channel

Cheers !

Answer (score 1):

I found the tutorials by following channel quite useful:
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCi9Mf3veSDDIMdGGtPmPu1g/videos
There is a series on smart contract development and another on dapp development using meteor